# Display the Count using join two table with store Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have a two table One is Payment another one CLuster.I have join two table using Store Proceudre Now the problem is I need to get the count

```
      Alter Procedure [dbo].[JKLL_Get_information_clusterwise_firstlevel_JMSL]
       AS
       Begin
         t1.Payment_ID=t2.ClusterID
        SELECT *,t2.ClusterName
         FROM JKLL_Payment_Upload t1, Cluster t2
        where Payment_Status=1 and Reject_Status=0 and First_Level_Approval_Status=0 
         END
```

Value are Coming with join table
now the problem is I need to get the count using Clustername
For example

```
            If(ClusterName="Usa")
    select count(Payment_ID) as value =15;
```

I need to get the count using PaymentID. can you some Edit above code Help me..

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP` and then you can `COUNT` what you have grouped like:

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.ClusterName), t2.ClusterName
FROM JKLL_Payment_Upload t1, Cluster t2
WHERE Payment_Status=1 and Reject_Status=0 and First_Level_Approval_Status=0 
GROUP BY t2.ClusterName
```

Remarks:

- Remark 1: When Grouping you cannot do a `SELECT *`.
- Remark 2: I added a `INNER JOIN` to your statement for performance considerations
- Remark 3: I would start without the Stored Procedure. Try to get you `SELECT` right in first place

UPDATE:

I am assuming tables like this:

[image]

Your data needs to have a relation. In this sample: `t1.ClusterID = t2.ClusterID`. So we can JOIN the tables with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.ClusterName) AS CountOfPayments, t2.ClusterName
FROM #JKLL_Payment_Upload t1
INNER JOIN #Cluster t2
    ON  t1.ClusterID = t2.ClusterID
--WHERE Payment_Status=1 and Reject_Status=0 and First_Level_Approval_Status=0 
GROUP BY t2.ClusterName
```

Comment: No values are coming

Comment: I do not know your data structure. Try without the JOIN. Updated answer

Comment: How we can use SP Witih condition

Comment: what do you mean with `within condition`?

Comment: Now values are coming 22 Usa,22-Canada,22-Japan when i run the First Store procedure I should get Usa 22 only then when i run the 2nd procedure i need to get Canada value and when i run the third procedure i need to get japan only